# Arduino / esp8266: error: section attribute not allowed for 'Pchr

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

My Arduino program had compiled and worked correctly but something happen or I did something because now when I compile it, I get an compiler error.  I have tried upgrading esp8266 v2.4.1 to 2.5.2 but then I get another error in the random.tcc header file.  I am compiling my code with Visual Studio 2017 with Visual Micro. I have seen this error on the web but upgrading didn't seem to help.

Any suggestions?

### OUTPUT

```
Adafruit_ESP8266.cpp:17: In file included from

Adafruit_ESP8266.h: 28:35: error: section attribute not allowed for 'Pchr
   typedef const PROGMEM char        Pchr; \\ Ditto, kindasorta
```

### SOURCE

```
#include <Adafruit_ESP8266.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>          //https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino

//needed for library
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>         //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager


// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup()
{
    Serial.println("Begin Setup");


    Serial.println("End Setup");
}

// the loop function runs over and over again until power down or reset
void loop()
{
    Serial.println("Begin Loop");


    Serial.println("End Loop");
}
```

Comment: The progmem is a way to keep constants in AVR Flash memory (even const/constexpr is copied into the ram). But if you're using ESP as an arduino, there is no need for it, as it's directly accessible over pointers. The main question: isn't the Adafruit_ESP for AVR Arduino + ESP module only?

Comment: I actually resolved the issue by removing the header file "Adafruit_ESP8266.h".

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error by removing the header file Adafruit_ESP8266.h.  I must of clicked on something that included it.